# If else loop in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a simple batch file where it will check the day, and if the day is 01 the program will move the files to a backup.

```
IF %day%==01(
move *.LST &dfs#\BackUp\
echo "Files moved successfully"
)ELSE (
"Files will get deleted only on 1st day of the month"
)
```

But it's throwing the error "Syntax is incorrect", can someone please check..

Comment: the else command has Echo in it, just forgot while adding in the question

Comment: Then please click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37922686/edit) button of the question and correct the code there!

Comment: 1. there are some spaces missing: one between `01` and `(`, and another one between `)` and `ELSE`; 2. you should write `IF "%day%"=="01"` to avoid trouble when `%day%` is empty; 3. you need to put the paths at the `move` command in between quotation marks, like `move "*.LST" "&dfs#\BackUp\"`, because the `&` is interpreted as command concatenation operator otherwise; 4. you should remove the quotation marks in the `echo` texts, unless you want them to be displayed also...

Comment: 1 and 2 I will agree, for 3 quotes are not req, it's working fine after I've used the below method.. and for 4, yeah I kept them intentionally

Comment: Alright; but (3) I still recommend to use quotation marks for paths in general in order to avoid trouble with special characters (`&`, `^`, `(`, `)`) and white-spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably %day% is not set properly, try this (adjust backup location):

```
@echo off
if %date:~-2%==01 ( 
    move *.lst backup
    echo files moved successfully
) else (
    echo files will get deleted only on 1st day of the month
)
```

Comment: working, thanks a lot..
I'm still wondering, I've used the same to get the day of the month and assigned to a variable.. don't know what went wrong

Comment: @BharathKumarReddy if this answer is helping you, give it an upvote. If it's a complete answer, accept it. That's how the site works, and you need to learn how it works if you want to use it.

Comment: @PaulTomblin my bad, I've already tried, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote